# Why does a style applied to a <td> override style applied to its parent <tr>?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style table with css by the use of :

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: black;}

td:nth-of-type(even) {background-color: green;}
```

But I'm asking why the `td:nth-of-type(even)` is stronger than the `tr:nth-child(odd)`?
The cells, that must receive both styles are always green, why?

Comment: Which rule appears first? Rules that come later have precedence, all else being equal.

Comment: @fred, even if I reverse the rules, this is the same result!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a matter of "strength", it's because `td` is a sub-element of `tr` in the DOM tree and any style that overrides the parent is applied to the child elements:

> According to the W3C HTML DOM standard, everything in an HTML document
>   is a node:
>
> The entire document is a document node Every HTML element is an
>   element node The text inside HTML elements are text nodes Every HTML
>   attribute is an attribute node Comments are comment nodes What this
>   means is that if you supplied a style for it (which you did), then
>   that style (or rule) will be evaluated and rendered.

For more info - look at this:

http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_nodes.asp

Answer (score 6):

The `td` element is on *top* of the `tr` element.  There is no specificity problem here, just stacking order.  You'd see the same problem with any other nested elements:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/moa13oth

```
<div class="a"><div class="b">Foo</div></div>

.a {
  background: black;
}

.b {
  background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: black;}

td:nth-of-type(even) {background-color: green;}

because in your CSS you have applied a style in td. which is the last rule. so basically what is in the last rule will override the previous rule as long as they conflict.

so if you want your style in tr to be followed. switch those lines. and then you may achieve what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

1) Cells are green.

2) Rows are black.

In your example each row of green cells fully overlaps the black row.

I expect that assigning margins to <td> will show also the underlying black color.

Also try adding a "td" after the (odd) rule:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) td {background-color: black;}
```

Answer (score -2):

<strike>When I style, I think of it as the style closest to the thing I'm styling wins.</strike>

Let me attempt to redeem myself here.  What I meant by the statement above is that I usually let me class selector drive most of my styling.  On the rare cases where I want to override that inline, then since the inline style ALONG WITH the class selector takes specificity.  Therefore, that inline element selector is "closer" to the thing I'm styling.

Also, when I'm writing my .css file, I keep in mind that the farther down the file it is, the "closer" it is to the thing I'm styling.  I base this on statement 8 from the [CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) article.

> When selectors have an equal specificity value, the latest rule is the one that counts.